# django.core.mail send_email with secure connection

Tags: django, ssl, django-email

Im trying to use django send_email function but it fails on authentication. In fact, django returns me message along the lines - ssl not found in this django installation.

I do have ssl-1.15 on my pythonpath and i could import it without errors. So the problem is probably with the certificates, right?

Now is there some kind of tutorial or example for generating those certificates, since the pakcage contains none. Could the problem be elsewhere?

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried importing ssl-1.15 from within Django? In other words, start ./manage.py shell and try to import ssl-1.15.

Did you find this [example?](http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/09/push-notification-and-python-django/) And [this one](http://coderseye.com/2008/setting-up-ssl-for-lighttpddjango.html) may even be better!

Comment: import ssl-1.15 gives import error. Importing ssl fails because it seems there is no ssl in this python. I do have put ssl-1.15 on my pythonpath, but since its virtual hosting without no shell access (meaning i cant run install scripts) - all i can do is put it on pythonpath in .fcgi file like this:
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PREFIX, "htdocs/modules/ssl-1.15"))
And it seems to be not working. importing other stuff (sorl-thumbnail, django-registration etc) works just fine like that.

Comment: Don't you know about virtualenv? I'm working myself on a shared Debian server. I'm not allowed to install anything into the system directory. With virtualenv I create my own Python environment and can install whatever I want. Checkout http://clemesha.org/blog/2009/jul/05/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/

Comment: Wait a minute. You've no shell access. That will be a show stopper for virtualenv. 

Other idea. Some python packages rely on things outside python. If I read the homepage of ssl-1.15 (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html) the same is true. If these objects are not available, or you are not allowed to run these programs then you're out of luck.

BTW in my (limited) experience, shell access makes life in the Python world much easier. You can fill your own toolkit, instead of using the providers toolkit. For example, my Cherrypy (in virtualenv) is 2 versions newer then Debian's one

Comment: Aye. If it were my own hosting account, i would surely pay for hosting that has shell access. Thanks for the info. I think that we are unable to find solution to this problem, but since you have provided lot of useful info ill mark the question answered. Thanks man!